# AWS Lambda in a VPC: random networking issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

We are using AWS lambdas to trigger some health checks to our live API. This lambda works as expected the majority of the time. However, randomly, it fails because of some networking issue, such as:

> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.example.com

I suspect the lambda is still cold starting, and its network is not ready yet.

Is there any best practice to test for the network availability on a lambda? Any configuration parameter to enforce? I thought testing the error message, and if it contains an `ENOTFOUND`, just ignore it and let the next call test the API. But that looks not optimal. :/

Note that the lambda is in a VPC, in case it is impacting.

Comment: Is it private API so that you need lambda in a VPC?

Comment: Thinking more about it, there is no reason actually. Can it have an impact? I'll try to extract it from our VPC. :)

Comment: Have it a go, and please let me know how it will go. With VPC, lambda has to use NAT gateway. NAT has [default timeout](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/nat-gateway-troubleshooting.html#nat-gateway-troubleshooting-timeout). Maybe this is what is causing your issue in VPC?

Comment: "I suspect the lambda is still cold starting, and its network is not ready yet." that's not how cold starts work. The server is fully running with networking fully available before it starts your Lambda function. This seems like some VPC setting, like maybe it's deploying in a public subnet sometimes, and a private subnet sometimes? Like was said above, remove it from the VPC if you don't actually need the function to access VPC resources.

Comment: How did it go? Did you try without VPC?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I didn't want to claim victory too early, but indeed, it seems it fixed the issue. No more similar error for 10 days now. Thanks a lot! :)